# What is this white stuff on an outside pillar of the alfesco?

Tags: walls, outdoor

Is on one side of a pillar that's holding up my alfesco.

Is this an indicator of water or something serious? This wall occassionally gets wet if it rains heavy enough and the rain blows sideways into it. However, the sides also get wet like that too and there doesn't seem to be damage there.

To get rid of it, do i simply need to scrap the paint off and re-paint over it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's efflorescence, an indicator of water coming out of the pillar. It could be rising damp. It could could be sort sort of leak.

Comment: It's caused by water soaking into the pillar, dissolving minerals, transporting them to the surface and then crystallising as it dries out.  If the pillar is new it could just be moisture from manufacture naturally drying out. If it gets wet from rain then that's the water source.  Neither of these are a problem - it's only concerning if it indicates water that shouldn't be there.

Comment: yes it's basically the same process as stalactite formation,  but water should not be getting inside the pillar,  perhaps the roof or cap is leaking.